# DataTemplate for a DataType - how to override this DataTemplate in a particular ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemtemplate, datatemplateselector

I have created several DataTemplates for some of the DataTypes in my pet project.
These data templates are really cool as they work like magic, magically transforming the look of the instances of the data types whenever and wherever they show up in the UI.
Now I want to be able to change the DataTemplate for these DataTypes in one particular ListBox. Does this mean I have to stop relying on WPF automatically applying the data template to the data types and assign a x:Key to the DataTemplates and then apply the Template/ItemTemplate in the UI using that key?

A ListBox contains items of various DataTypes (all derived from a common base class) and as it is now, all magically works without specifying a TemplateSelector, as the correct template is chosen by the actual data type of the item in the listBox. If I went for using the x:Key to apply DataTemplates, would I then need to write a TemplateSelector?

I am new to this and only experimenting with DataTemplates. One moment I think, wow, how cool! And then I want a different data template for the same data type in a different list box and ooops, I can't do it :-) Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify an `ItemTemplate` specifically for your `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- your template here -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Or alternatively, if you have already defined your `DataTemplate` in a `ResourceDictionary` somewhere:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
      <!-- your template here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can reference it on the `ListBox` using:

```
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" />
```

You do not need to write a template selector for either of these approaches to work

---

**Example** in response to comments

The example below demonstrates defining a default `DataTemplate` for a data type (in this case, `String`) for a window and then overridding it within a listbox:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
            <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10" Margin="3" Fill="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Height="10" Width="10" Margin="3" Fill="Blue" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <sys:String>One</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Two</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Three</sys:String>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This produces the following UI:

[image: Example Display]

Comment: The DataTemplate I have in my ResourceDictionary is targeting a particular DataType and WPF applies the template to any instance of that data type automatically wherever it shows up, so even when I set the ItemTemplate of the ListBox to {x:Null}, the items still show up templated.

Comment: If you set the `ItemTemplate` to `{x:Null}` I would expect it to use the default template - do you still get the same behaviour if you explicitly specify a template?

Comment: Thank you for your post. I managed to apply a different ItemTemplate to the elements in that 'special' listbox yesterday, I can't remember what exactly was the problem, it was something subtle. But part of the question remains - since there are three different types of objects in the listbox. For each of these data types I specified a DataTemplate, now, in that one particular listbox I would like these data types to look different. I can explicitly set the ItemTemplate which will then override the datatemplates mentioned earlier, however, i then get only one data template for all three types..

Comment: If you have multiple data types in your list box, you *will* need to implement a template selector